# Using one collection only with MongoDb

Tags: python, mongodb

Here is the **quick** version:

Is it OK to keep all the documents of a MongoDb database in one `stuff` collection instead of organizing the database in distinct `students`, `schools` and `messages` collections?

Here is the **long** version:

I am learning to work with MongoDb for a new application with a database organized like this:

```
db.messages
{'recipients': ['student 1', 'student 2', 'school 1', 'school 2'], 'text': 'hello!'}

db.students
{'_id': 1, 'name': 'mary'}
{'_id': 2, 'name': 'joseph'}

db.schools
{'_id': 1, 'name': 'middle'}
{'_id': 2, 'name': 'high'}
```

Looking for a list of all recipients of a message requires to transform the `recipients` list into two lists, then run one query per collection. On top of this extra work, it would be difficult to use the `skip` and `limit` with `sort` by date (the `skip` would have to be done by the application after aggregating the two query results, not by the database).

I think it would be much easier if the database was organized like this:

```
db.stuff
{'_id': 1, '_type': 'message', 'recipients': [2, 3, 4, 5], 'text': 'hello!'}
{'_id': 2, '_type': 'student', 'name': 'mary'}
{'_id': 3, '_type': 'student', 'name': 'joseph'}
{'_id': 4, '_type': 'school', 'name': 'middle'}
{'_id': 5, '_type': 'school', 'name': 'high'}
db.stuff.create_index([('_type', 1)])
```

With this organization one query can find documents of any type and the flexibility on the queries is much higher. Removing the collections makes the database more *schema-less*.

After reading (most of) the documentation and a bunch of blogs, I think the only limitation is that the maximum [number of indexes per collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Number-of-Indexes-per-Collection) is 64.

Is that 64 the only limitation? Or am I missing something that could bite me later?

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you're more than welcome to store all of your data in a single collection and implement your own way of finding different types of data (you're using a `_type` attribute which works fine). I'm unaware of any other limitations MongoDB has when storing tons of data in a single collection vs. multiple collections.

However, this is a really bad idea in practice. First and foremost, your data is well-structured and would be easier to work with if you had a formal schema (like in a regular SQL database). Mongo really shines when you have blobs of data that looks like JSON but every element has slightly different fields. Imagine getting data from an API which gives you a JSON blob with 100 different keys but you're only interested in two or three fields right now. Storing the whole blob in Mongo would make sense because it would be really easy to query all of those extra fields in the future.

With all of that said, any major database will probably be able to handle all of your queries in a few milliseconds with a couple of indexes.

In your particular case, I think you should fix your schema instead of merging collections. In particular, the `recipients` list on every message is (I assume) a list of IDs for documents in two different collections. If schools and students are significantly different, then they probably shouldn't be lumped together as `recipients`. If students and schools are nearly identical, I'd put those into a single collection (called `recipients`) and add a field called `isStudent` to distinguish the two. While this is similar to your `_type` field, messages have no business being in the same collection as the other two.

If schools and students are significantly different but you insist on having a single list of `recipients`, I'd recommend adding a `recipients` table which includes all of the common fields between `schools` and `students`. You would also need a `recipientId` attached to every `school` and `student`. So something like this:

```
db.messages
{ recipients: [RecipientIds], text: String }

db.recipients
{ name: String } // Add additional shared attributes here.

db.students
{ recipientId: ObjectId, school: ObjectId, birthday: Date, ... }

db.schools
{ recipientId: ObjectId, phone: String, ... }
```

Comment: Your suggestions make sense, but I feel like you are telling me to treat MongoDb like an SQL database with normalized data, and the more I think about it, the more collections I want to create, which scares me because I'm afraid that the lack of joins across collections will be a big limit. My recipients example is one of many in my mind. Following your "be organized" example adds some complexity to the design and limitations to the type of queries. I hoped to use MongoDb to have more flexibility, not less.

Comment: From your answer I don't understand the disadvantages, other than "this is a really bad idea in practice".

Comment: Without a schema, it is very difficult to validate that your data is correct. This makes working with your data much more difficult. Now you need to do significantly more data validation checks outside of the database to make sure your data looks right (every field you're expecting is present and contains some non-null value). This gets even worse when you start changing the format of your data. It's very difficult to migrate your data to a newer format so the code interacting with the DB will constantly be getting more complicated to deal with old and new data.